# How to reset an elements class to it's initial value

Tags: javascript

How can I reset an elements 'class' attribute to it's initial value?

I am building a tooltip popup which starts with class="ttPopup".  This is then set to the appropriate orientation by adding classes such as class="ttPopup top left".

Problem is when the Popup windows closes, how do I reset the class to it's original value ready for the next time?

Comment: just manually store it.

Comment: there is no specific DOM method for it - you will have to store it manually

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you could do it:

- store in a custom attribute
- store in a javascript array
- store in localStorage
- etc.

Answer (score 0):

Not completely sure if I am correct to use a custom property on the element or not but here is the solution I have used at the moment:

```js
eTooltip.addEventListener("mouseenter", function (oEvent) { ttOpen(oEvent); } );
eTooltip.addEventListener("mouseleave", function (oEvent) { ttClose(oEvent); } );

function ttOpen(oEvent) {
 var thisPopup = oEvent.target.getElementsByClassName("ttPopup")[0];
 thisPopup.origClassName = thisPopup.className;
}

function ttClose(oEvent) {
 var thisPopup = oEvent.target.getElementsByClassName("ttPopup")[0];
 if (thisPopup.origClassName) { thisPopup.className = thisPopup.origClassName; thisPopup.origClassName = null; }
 console.log(thisPopup.className)
}
```

Thanks for your help.